# Running PHP,MySQL and apache in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I have installed native apache and mysql,php in my linux server. I tried a page using phpinfo() and it worked.But when I try my own pages, the execution of the page stops when it comes to the php tag, even the css tag following it doesn't come to the browser. Please help me how to fix this issue.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure that there are no syntax errors in your script? Check the display_errors setting in php.ini and set it to "on" in order to display php errors. More info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php and maybe you want to post the script you made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using php short tags, by chance?

```
<? ?> 
<?= ?>
```

Ubuntu 10.04 is running php 5.3.2.

Shorts tags were deprecated in 5.3.

Answer (score 1):

you probably have an error in your php. At the top of the document try adding:

`<?php ini_set('display_errors', 1); ?>`

See if there is any error output...

Answer (score 1):

If the php file is in public_html directory (userdir), you must edit the file:

```
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf
```

and comments from line 8-15

```
# To re-enable php in user directories comment the following lines
# (from <IfModule ...> to </IfModule>.) Do NOT set it to On as it
# prevents .htaccess files from disabling it.
#<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
#    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
#        php_admin_value engine Off
#    </Directory>
#</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure the following lines are in your apache2.conf and uncommented:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
```

Comment: If this were the issue wouldny it just show the php as plain text?